# How to subset nan/inf values in Dato SFrames

Tags: python, sframe

Im trying to subset a column of a large data frame with a couple nan/inf values in one of the columns.

I have tried for example something like this.

```
df = df[df['a'] == 'NaN']
```

Or

```
df = df[df['a'] == 'Inf']
```

How do I reference these types of values within a column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NaN is a special value. It is not equal to anything, not even itself.  Here's one way to filter by NaN:

```
import math
df = df[df['a'].apply(lambda x: math.isnan(x))]
```

Inf is a little easier:

```
df = df[df['a'] == float('inf')]
```

Answer (score 0):

You know it's a dictionary so you can't use comprehension but you can iterate:

```
subset = {}

for d in df:
   if d['a']=='Nan':
         subset.update(d)

print subset
```